# How to get fileName from http when downloading?

Tags: java, apache-camel

How can one get the file name from a http GET using Camel?

The headers are not revealing anything useful and the file name created is something dynamically generated…

```
2018-03-12 18:19:12.729 DEBUG 83572 --- [er://downloader] o.a.camel.component.http.HttpProducer    : Executing http GET method: http://firds.esma.europa.eu/firds/DLTINS_20180312_01of01.zip
2018-03-12 18:19:12.777 DEBUG 83572 --- [er://downloader] o.a.camel.component.http.HttpProducer    : Http responseCode: 200
2018-03-12 18:19:12.790  INFO 83572 --- [er://downloader] FIRDS Download                           : {Accept-Ranges=bytes, breadcrumbId=ID-MGR-MacBook-Space-local-1520875148898-0-1, CamelHttpMethod=GET, CamelHttpResponseCode=200, CamelHttpResponseText=OK, Content-Length=32723, Content-MD5=7t9wKjv9rUcwarKlfrKC7w==, Content-Type=application/octet-stream, Date=Mon, 12 Mar 2018 17:19:12 GMT, Etag="0x8D587B14BA2F5A1", firedTime=Mon Mar 12 18:19:12 CET 2018, Last-Modified=Mon, 12 Mar 2018 00:36:29 GMT, Server=ECAcc (sto/DB4C), Set-Cookie=citrix_ns_id=1wBsjlP8vQbSRF9tbnHZFAVg4IE0000; Domain=.esma.europa.eu; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=157680000, X-Cache=HIT, x-ms-blob-type=BlockBlob, x-ms-lease-state=available, x-ms-lease-status=unlocked, x-ms-request-id=c3469ad7-001e-0022-6515-baa9f5000000, x-ms-version=2014-02-14}
2018-03-12 18:19:12.791 DEBUG 83572 --- [er://downloader] o.a.c.c.file.GenericFileProducer         : Starting producer: Producer[file://input]
2018-03-12 18:19:12.791 DEBUG 83572 --- [er://downloader] org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache      : Adding to producer cache with key: file://input for producer: Producer[file://input]
2018-03-12 18:19:12.791 DEBUG 83572 --- [er://downloader] o.a.c.processor.SendDynamicProcessor     : >>>> file://input Exchange[ID-MGR-MacBook-Space-local-1520875148898-0-3]
2018-03-12 18:19:12.799 DEBUG 83572 --- [er://downloader] o.a.camel.component.file.FileOperations  : Using InputStream to write file: input/ID-MGR-MacBook-Space-local-1520875148898-0-4
2018-03-12 18:19:12.806 DEBUG 83572 --- [er://downloader] o.a.c.c.file.GenericFileProducer         : Wrote [input/ID-MGR-MacBook-Space-local-1520875148898-0-4] to [file://input]
```

Example:

```
from("timer://downloader?repeatCount=1")
                .routeId("FIRDS Download")
                .to(fromStr)
                .split()
                .tokenizeXML("doc", "result")
                .streaming()
                .log("${body}")
                .bean(HttpDownload.class)
                .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("GET"))
                .toD("${body}")
                .log("${headers}")
                .toD("file:input")
                .end();
```

Comment: That depends on what the HTTP server respond with, and if the file is in multipart, a http header or something else. Your details is a bit too limited how the file is downloaded.

Comment: The server responds with a .zip-file to be downloaded. This is the link I'm trying to retrieve: http://firds.esma.europa.eu/firds/FULINS_C_20180310_01of01.zip. It is dynamically calculated…

Comment: Do you not already have the name as part of the http url you call? If so you can set the CamelFileName header with that name then the file component will use that as a name.

Comment: From the headers you log it does not seem to show that the HTTP server returns `Content-Disposition` or similar header with what the filename should be. But if you want the same name as in the url, then you can set that CamelFileName header to that value.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using, and which Camel component do you use for calling the HTTP server?

Comment: We use 2.20.2 with http/http4 and I think I solved by using the download link, a processor and CamelOverruleFileName… It's isn't a beauty but it works…